# Transforming table

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have a table like this

Type, Year, Month, Sales

I want to split the Type columns to several columns and transform the table to

year, month , type A sales, type B sales, type C sales

We actually dont know the number of type we have as well

Comment: Since you don't know the number of types, search for dynamic pivots -- lots of examples on SO.

Comment: thank you, I am new to sql. I didn't know what terms to google haha